# db4o unique field on inherited fields

Tags: db4o

i am trying to make a subclass unique by applying a unique constraint on a db4o object's inherited field? Is it possible?

ex: class B inherits field f from class A and i need to make f unique only for class B.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is not possible. You only can make a field unique on the class it is defined on. In this case it's class A.

It's not possible to mark a field inherited from class A, as unique only for the subclass B.